# Normal distribution problem; distribution of height

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

The problem is: the height of children in age from 3.5 to 4 years is described by normal distribution with parameters $\mu =103$ centimetres and $  \sigma=4.5$ centimetres. What is the percent of children with height $\le$ 93 centimetres?
Normally, I would count $F(93) = P(X \le 93) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$, but here, I am puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal distribution by creating the z-score
$$
z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{X-103}{4.5}
$$
and then compute
$$
P\left(z<= \frac{93-103}{4.5} = -\frac{10}{4.5}\right)
$$

Comment: Do I have to count $\int_{-\infty}^{-10 \over 4.5} e^{-z/2}dz$?